# Find dimension of $V+W$ from given system and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I have to find dimension of $V+W,$ where$ V$ is a vector subspace given by solutions of the linear system:

$$x+2y+z=0$$
    $$3y+z+3t=0$$

and $W$ is the subspace generated from vectors
$(4,0,1,3)^T,(1,0,-1,0)^T$.

I don't know how to combine the two subspaces and calculate the dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The dimension of the basis of the solution space is $2$.

Also, none of the vectors in the basis of $W$ is a solution to the linear system.

Can you compute the dimension of $V+W$ now?

Comment: How did you find the solution of the system?

Comment: user4789408  By using hints, after thinking about how they may help you, and hunkering down to complete the solution, since you've been given the tools you need to do so.  Appreciate the help you get.  Don't pander for more and more, essentially asking : "Do it for me!!  Whah! Whah!

Comment: @amWhy I have a different result and it could be helpful if I find a possible mistake I made.

Comment: Then I suggest you post your different result in your question.  This is a "you first" sort of site:  asker starts with a complete question, definitions as needed, the time and effort the asker has put (including such details) and any findings/solutions one has obtained via the displayed work.  Then you can ask the more specific work you've done, and ask why your work and solution does not match up to others.  You reveal the hand you've been dealt, as best you can, and answers will be able to see more clearly see any relevant errors, and ultimately help you to more effectively understand.

Comment: @user4789408, I did make a mistake earlier. In general, a basis is not unique.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I know it, I was curious to know how did you find it. I am going to edit the post with results

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the dimension of $V\cap W$. A vector $v=\lambda{}^{\mathrm t}(4,0,1,3)+\mu{}^{\mathrm t}(1,0,-1,0)={}^{\mathrm t}(4\lambda+\mu,0,\lambda-\mu,3\lambda)$ satisfies the equations of both planes if and only if
$$\begin{cases}x+2y+z=5\lambda=0\\3y+z+3t=10\lambda-\mu=0\end{cases}\iff \lambda=\mu=0.$$
Hence $V\cap W=\{0\}$, $V+W=V\oplus W$ and
$$\dim(V+W)=\dim V+\dim W=4.$$

Comment: Do think it was a good call to answer the entire problem, step-by-step, and producing the final answer for the OP to claim as his/her own?  Please study Siong's solution, which is just right, (where your solution is "too much"

Comment: @amWhy: I didn't give all details and the O.P. has to add  justifications

Comment: That is true, for the most part;  Note that I haven't downvoted or flagged the answer; was more letting you know how your answer appeared to me upon first encountering it.

Comment: Usually, I give a sketch, more or less detailed. I rarely give hints that look like puzzles (at least from my point of view…)